# OPEs of exponentials

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

Given a holomorphic field $H(z)$ with OPE: $$H(z)H(0)\sim -\ln z$$ What is the most smart way to calculate the OPE's of the exponential operators $e^{\pm iH(z)}$, given as follows? $$e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)} \sim \frac{1}{z},$$ $$e^{iH(z)}e^{iH(0)} \sim 0,$$ $$e^{-iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)} \sim 0.$$ Should I expand $\exp$ and do term by term? Or is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Expanding and rearranging terms certainly works, which is how this is computed in ie tong. Not sure what is the most “clever” approach or even whether that is well defined.

Comment: Hi @BVquantization. Is this from Polchinski section 10.3?

Comment: Hint: Just use $$e^{iA H(z)} e^{iB H(w)}= (z-w)^{AB}e^{(iA H(z)+iB H(w))} $$ This gives you the leading behaviour you are looking for. It's a well known formula (apparently) and a proof can be found in e.g. Difrancesco CFT, Chap. 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. Note that there are implicitly written radial order ${\cal R}$ and normal order $::$ at various places in OP's equations.
2. The starting point is the 2-point relation
   $$\begin{align}{\cal R}(A(z)B(w)) ~-~:A(z)B(w):
   ~=~& C(z,w)~{\bf 1}, \cr 
   C(z,w)~\equiv~&\langle \Omega | {\cal R}(A(z)B(w))|\Omega\rangle,\end{align} \tag{1} $$
   cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. The relevant [Wick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) is a nested Wick's theorem
   $$ \begin{align} {\cal R}(:e^{A(z)}::e^{B(w)}:)~=~&\exp\left( C(z,w)\frac{\partial}{\partial A(z)}\frac{\partial}{\partial B(w)}\right): e^{A(z)+B(w)}:\cr ~=~&\ldots~=~e^{C(z,w)}: e^{A(z)+B(w)}:\cr
   ~=~&e^{C(z,w)}\left(: e^{A(w)+B(w)}:~+~{\cal O}(z\!-\!w)\right)
   ,\end{align}  \tag{2}$$
   cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451).